# TFS Moving branch to newly created folder

Tags: branching-and-merging

We are currently restructuring our source control. I moved a branch and now all history seems to have been removed. I would like to rollback the branch to a previous changeset. Is there a way to still be able to rollback a branch that has been moved? I'm a newbie to TFS administration so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Moved Branch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My findings are as follows:

If your folders are contained within a Parent folder you may still roll back any changes based upon the parent folder's history. Otherwise history is lost upon moving a branch to a new location.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Thanks!